# remove delay in updating scrolltop/ scrollleft of an element on scroll event of other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, webview, scrolltop

I want to create a table which has first row & first column fixed. For this I have referred [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/software_christian/Fp9a3/8/). It works fine in desktop browser view but I want to create this table for webview in which, while updating scrolltop of row & column headers wrt the content of table it flicks i.e. there's a delay while updating the scrolltop/scrollleft.

This might be because there is a delay while calculating scrolltop/scrollleft of source element and then updating these value to target element (the reflow & repaint concept).

I want to remove this delay or minimize it as far as possible,  as it is hampering the performance in webview.

I have tried with throttle-debounce.js but still the same.

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="upperCorner"></div>
    <div id="columnHeader">....</div>
    <div id="rowHeader">....</div>
    <div id="mainContent">.....</div>
</div>
```

Here's script

```
$(function(){
var $$ = {//cache of jQuery objects
    content: $("#mainContent"),
    months: $("#columnHeader"),
    status: $("#rowHeader"),
};
    $$.content.scroll(function() {
        $$.status.scrollTop($$.content.scrollTop());
        $$.months.scrollLeft($$.content.scrollLeft());
    });

    $$.months.scroll(function() {
        $$.content.scrollLeft($$.months.scrollLeft());
    } );

    $$.vaccine.scroll( function() {
        $$.content.scrollTop($$.status.scrollTop());
    });

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Any immediate help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the animate function instead of scrollTop if you want to change the animation speed.

```
$("#element").animate({ "top": 100+"px" }, 1000)
```

To remove animation/delay all together you can use

```
$("#element").css("top", position+"px")
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate response but I don't want the element to animate instead the target element should move parallel to the source element without any delay.